# Spark Framework and relative path

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, relative-path, spark-java

I'm using the [Spark framework](http://sparkjava.com/) to create a web app and I've been going through the tutorials on their site. At the moment, I'm working on their templates section, however I can't seem to get the project to recognize that my css and my templates are in my resources folder.

I'm using Netbeans and Maven to manage my dependencies.

Can anyone help me figure out how to set up my relative paths/create my project folders appropriately in this environment? I'm a newbie to both Maven and Spark, so go easy please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Static Files:

If your resources directory looked like this:

```
resources
└───public
    ├───css
    │       style.css
    ├───html
    │       hello.html
    └───templates
            template.ftl
```

You could use `staticFiles.location("/public")`. This would make `/public` the root staticFiles directory.

You could then access `hello.html` like this: `http://{host}:{port}/html/hello.html`

If you wanted to use an external location on the filesystem, you could use `staticFiles.externalLocation(...)`, which works pretty much the same way above.

> Note: `staticFiles.externalLocation(...)` can be set to your project's resources directory, which means that the files will be automatically refreshed (useful for development)

A more in depth explanation can be found in [the spark documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#static-files)

### Configuring your template engine:

If you have already set the staticFiles location, but spark is still having trouble finding your templates, try this.

> Note: These examples are for the FreeMarker engine, though they should apply to other engines with minor tweaking.

After looking through the [examples](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/09/22/spark-minitwit.html), it seems that by default, a `new FreemarkerEngine()` looks for templates in `spark/template/freemarker`, and **not** your staticFiles location.

You have two options:

1: Move all of your templates to that directory

*or*

2: Configure your own engine, and pass it instead when defining routes

```
FreeMarkerEngine freemarker = new FreeMarkerEngine();
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setTemplateLoader(
        new ClassTemplateLoader(YOUR_CLASS.class, "/templatedir"));
freemarker.setConfiguration(config);
```

Comment: I'll give this a go tomorrow morning. I've marked it as the answer because it's very useful information!

You are correct that I was already setting the staticFileLocation for my templates folder. Additionally, I have a few CSS files I'm trying to point my HTML files to and those can't be found either, which has me all sorts of confused. As for the templates, I'll give your code a go tomorrow and let you know how things go! I appreciate the response!

Comment: I wound up installing IntelliJ and for some reason the exact same code works out of IntelliJ that doesn't work in Netbeans. Oy vey!